# How to limit the format of django-rest-framework-api uploading(post method)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, file-upload, django-rest-framework

In fact, I need your help to limit my API to upload

I only need Jason  and excel formats(csv,xls,xlsl) on the server-side, but I did not find any code for that.

The second question is, what methods should I use to authenticate the user?

Here's [a link](https://blog.vivekshukla.xyz/uploading-file-using-api-django-rest-framework/) that I use its code in my API

in fact, I need fix this part:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser, JSONParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from .serializers import FileSerializer

class FileView(APIView):

  parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
    if file_serializer.is_valid():
      file_serializer.save()
      return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
      return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def get():
    pass

def update():
    pass
```

my model :

```
from django.db import models

class File(models.Model):

  file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
  remark = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and my serializers :

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import File

class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta():
    model = File
    fields = ('file', 'remark', 'timestamp')
```

but I didn't know how most make it limit
my Django version is 2 AND my python version is 3 
I will thank you if you help me :)
have to go coding time

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @cezar i read it it and i edit my topic and i will hope this is minimal and complete

Comment: please show `FileSerializer` and model

Comment: @BearBrown i add it